# Dropzone.js - Combine with normal form - ask about positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone and try to combine it with normal form  so I read this tutorial https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone
and yeah I can do it successfully. However, I want other input text field and submit-button to be outside of form tag (outside of dropzone)  so I use css `position:absolute` the text input to be above the form  and submit-button below form

but I forgot that if I select image to upload the form dropzone's height will extend. so It fail. (see the screenshot)

[image]

```
<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" style="position:relative">
  <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> 

  Username : <input type="text" name="username" style="position:absolute; top:-50px; left:0px; /> <br/>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" style="position:absolute; top:-40px;left:0px; /> <br/>

  <button type="submit" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:0px;">Submit data and files!</button>
</form>
```

I even move the button to outside of form and use html5 attribute `form="my-awesome-dropzone"`  but it's not work. How could I do?

Comment: I think a fiddle would be nice here but from the looks of it, if you remove all of the inline css on button, it will move out of the way when files are added to dropzone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way, a padding of `20px` to the form at bottom, and append `button` to `absolute, bottom: 0px`, and it will be at end of form, even if there's uploaded images.

```js
$(function(){
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", { url: "/file/post"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.dropzonejs.com/new-js/dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.dropzonejs.com/css/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone" style="position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;">

  <input type="email" name="username" /><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" /><br>

  <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> 
  
  <button type="submit" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">Submit data and files!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem of dropzone overlapping submit button is due to form having `style="position:relative"` and button having `style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:0px;"`. Remove both of them.

Comment: If I remove it will look like to the first case in my screenshot

Comment: @doflamingo ok, what if you remove dropzone class from the form itself, create a div and add class to that div? Attaching dropzone to an element inside the form instead of entire form.

Comment: I used to write your method.  the position was perfect but... it cannot simultaneously submit with other normal form

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a strange way of achieving what you want. I checked the documentation and in the Tips & Tricks section (https://docs.dropzone.dev/misc/tips) it clearly states that you can put an element inside your dropzone element with the class dz-message and dropzone will not create the message for you. So I would suggest that you do like I've done and above your submit button place the following element:

```
<div class="dz-message">
    <div>Upload file here</div>
 </div>
```

The negative aspect is that `dictDefaultMessage` isn't then honoured.

Also, if javascript is disabled then the div will still show, in which case add this to your css:

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        .dz-message {display:none;}
    </style>
</noscript>
```